# How to change Bluetooth codec, programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings, codec

We have an option of changing the current Bluetooth codec for the paired device in the **Developer Settings**, as shown below.

[image: Change bluetooth codec]

Is there any workaround by changing the system settings, to **programmatically** change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Not as an application developer, as the codec negotiation is part of the Bluetooth stack. But if you can change the Bluetooth stack sources, it might be possible. Over at appuals there is a nice article on how to do this:
[How to Modify Bluetooth Stacks on Android for Greatly Enhanced Bluetooth Audio Quality](https://appuals.com/how-to-modify-bluetooth-stacks-on-android-for-greatly-enhanced-bluetooth-audio-quality/)

Comment: My question is not about changing the Bluetooth Stack on Android, but changing the codec which the paired earphones are using. I can change it using the UI in Developer Settings. So, is there any way to change it like from **AAC -> SBC**, programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the standard implementation of the API will not allow this to be done.

But no one is stopping us from extending the standard API.
Extended APIs can be obtained [HERE](https://github.com/Reginer/aosp-android-jar)

Next, we get the **BluetoothA2dp** class and pick up new methods:
**getCodecStatus, getCodecConfig, getCodecType**

We collect **BluetoothCodecConfig** and apply **setCodecConfigPreference(device, newConfig)**

Example:
object : ServiceListener

```
            a2dp = proxy as BluetoothA2dp
            val device: BluetoothDevice = a2dp.activeDevice
            val status: BluetoothCodecStatus = a2dp.getCodecStatus(device)
            val config = status.codecConfig
            val codec = config.codecType
            val newConfig = BluetoothCodecConfig(0, 1000 * 1000, SAMPLE_RATE_44100, BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16, CHANNEL_MODE_STEREO, 32771, 49152, 0, 0)
            a2dp.setCodecConfigPreference(device, newConfig)
            val updatedStatus: BluetoothCodecStatus = a2dp.getCodecStatus(device)
            val updatedConfig = updatedStatus.codecConfig
```